# error"[rospack] Warning: no such package vrep_ros_plugin"

Tags: ros, vrep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros indigo and vrep pro edu.The Vrep is working is fine but the plugin is not working.Can anyone provide me a solution for this error?

error"[rospack] Warning: no such package vrep_ros_plugin"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198829/error%22%5Brospack%5D-warning:-no-such-package-vrep_ros_plugin%22/) by [Annaiyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21016/annaiyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-12-03**:
Also, I believe their package is called `vrep_plugin` if you have a `package.xml` looking for `vrep_ros_plugin`, that could be where your error is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you copy the V-Rep ROS packages to your workspace and re-build your workspace as suggested in their tutorial: http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/en/rosTutorialHydro.htm ? I think that might help solve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0